# How does Hotline Miami save?

Tags: hotline-miami, hotline-miami-2

So I'm going to for the all ground executions achievement. I want to make sure my execution saves so I can move onto the next weapon. I don't want to complete the full level obviously. But how does Hotline Miami autosaves work? Does it autosave when you die? Complete a level? Move onto the next stage?

Answer (score 2):

It saves the chapter you're in, allowing you to go back and go through it from the beginning, so when you move to a new chapter you'll have that auto-saved.